# AngularJS Clock Factory, $timeout woes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I'm refactoring a web application I'm writing and would like to move a controller into a factory (if it's possible the the correct structure) so I can include it in different controllers throughout my app. I can't seem to wrap my head around how I should use $timeout. I would like to remove redundant code as well by having one function pass in the offset.

Obligatory: I'm new to AngularJS.

```
App.controller('TimeCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
    // Set and update clocks
    var update = function(){
        $scope.est_time = moment.utc().add(-5, 'hours').format('h:mm:ss A');
        $scope.cst_time = moment.utc().add(-6, 'hours').format('h:mm:ss A');
        $scope.cet_time = moment.utc().add(+1, 'hours').format('h:mm:ss A');
        $scope.ist_time = moment.utc().add(+5.5, 'hours').format('h:mm:ss A');
        $timeout(update, 1000);
    };
    update();
}]);
```

Is it possible to move this into a factory so I can eventually use `{{Time.getTime(-5)}}` in my view? Or even just `Time.getTime()` in a controller?

I've come up with this. While it works, I'm not sure how to incorporate the `$timeout` functionality.

```
App.factory('Time', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
    return {
        getTime: function (tz){
            return moment.utc().add(tz, 'hours').format('h:mm:ss A');
        }   
    };
}]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory return native js-object. Above `return` is possible to write any functions. Try it.

```
App.factory('Time', ['$interval', function($interval){
    var utc;
    $interval(function() {
        utc = moment.utc();
    }, 1000);

    return {
        getTime: function (tz){
            return utc.add(tz, 'hours').format('h:mm:ss A');
        }   
    };
}]);
```

I want to add to the above. Filters exist in Angular. Filters convert a data: get data model and return the formating data. Perhaps, you need it. More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter

Comment: This doesn't appear to continually update like I want. Does the method get destroyed after it renders?

Comment: @Randy, why not continually? See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fenex/c941g14g/). Factory lives until your application lives.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. I found my issue. Moment being a pain.